# Modify a text file without creating another one with a batch (.bat) file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

Let’s suppose I have this text file:

```
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
_________1_________2_________3_________4_________5_________6_________7
*0000000000003000345800185000000000000002052017108018010009990
*000000000000302082890010000000000T SECTEUR SANITAIRE JIJEL  1
*000000000000306758680008500000000TIC ZIAMA MANSOURIAH       1
```

The header and all the lines contain 62 characters.
if you look at the header and start from the position 42 you’ll see `022017`, `02` is the current month and `2017` is the year ; from position 48 to 62 (i.e after `052017`) we have 14 values (`10801801000999`) and a `0` (zero).

The last line contains   or let’s say it’s not identical to the other lines.

Let’s say I have several files of the same structure ; and I want to set the date in the header to the current date, (we are in august 2019, so i want to get `082019` in the header instead of `052017`).
After the date (`052017`) i want to remove the values that come after (in this case (`10801801000999`) and replace them by spaces and keep the value (0), in a way that the header keep its 62 characters.
Can someone help me write some code (a batch file : .bat) to do the job ?
Especially if I have several text files and each one of them contains more than 5000 lines.

Comment: Your description doesn't exactly match your data. Also you can't `edit` a text file via batch without writing to a ***new*** file and if necessary renaming afterwards. Read about [substrings](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Answer (score 1):

The following batch will

- iterate files *.txt in the current folder,
- rename the original to .bak extension
- read header, modify and write it to the original name
- copy the remainder of the saved file

**BTW SuperUser isn't a script writing service,

a bit more of own research and coding attempts could be expected.**

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\08\16\SU_1472064.cmd
@Echo off
:: Get MonthYear
for /f "usebackq" %%A in (`
  powershell -NoP -C "(Get-Date).ToString('MMyyyy')"
`) Do Set MonthYear=%%A

:: iterate .txt files in current folder
For /f "delims=" %%F in ('Dir /B /O-D *.txt') Do Call :sub "%%~F"
Echo Job done

Goto :Eof

:Sub filename
:: Rename original file to .bak extension
Ren %1 "%~1.bak"
:: read header line
Set /p "Header=" <"%~1.bak"
Echo 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
Echo _________1_________2_________3_________4_________5_________6_________7
Echo %Header%
Set "NewHeader=%Header:~0,41%%MonthYear%              0"
Echo %NewHeader%
(Echo %NewHeader%
 More +1 "%~1.bak"
) > %1
```

Sample output:

```
> SU_1472064.cmd
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
_________1_________2_________3_________4_________5_________6_________7
*0000000000003000345800185000000000000002052017108018010009990
*0000000000003000345800185000000000000002082019              0
Job done
```

Comment: Simply check it out, the screen output just shows the changed header, the ''file' itself as you expect.

Comment: LotPings thank a lot for your time but I want to get this                                                                                *0000000000003000345800185000000000000002082019              0
*000000000000302082890010000000000T SECTEUR SANITAIRE JIJEL  1
*000000000000306758680008500000000TIC ZIAMA MANSOURIAH       1